# WCF service for CRUD --internal only

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service, crud

How can I achieve this design..

I have a table example : Customers with  4 fields.

I have developed a WCF service as customerinfo.mycompanyName.com/LookUpservic.svc which will provide access to Customers table data.

The above lookup service will be made accessible  outside our office network since public facing websites needs to access the data from customers table.

Also I need to develop a website for editing the customers data. This website will not be accessed outside our office network and it will be windows based authentication . All the operations CRUD needs to be done in WCF. So I thought of developing another service as 
customerinfo.mycompanyName.com/CRUD.svc . But since 
customerinfo.mycompanyName.com/LookUpservic.svc will be made available to public (out side network) even customerinfo.mycompanyName.com/CRUD.svc will be available to public right ?.

Since the DNS entry for customerinfo.mycompanyName.com will be port forwarded. How can I achieve writing another service for CRUD over customerinfo.mycompanyName.com without being made available to public ?.

Any other suggestions ?
Thanks for help in advance...

Comment: Bind the WebServices to different IPs (and different names) - this way you can port forward selectively... BUT this won't provide real security IMHO... when designing security you need to evaluate your risk scenarios and define appropriate measures (esp. depending on business impact).

Comment: Since you said "This website will not be accessed outside our office network and it will be windows based authentication"; use Windows Authentication for your CRUD.svc and it will only be available for use for users on your domain even if it is technically visible externally. But I agree with @Yahia; without knowing your risk scenarios, it's tough to call.

Comment: You can [apply security to each endpoint for every WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362(v=vs.110).aspx), much more fine-grained than the "all or nothing" approach you get from IIS. That being said, why do you want this apparently internal service to reside in the same IIS application as an external-facing service?